# Using Vlookup inside Large function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to use more than one Vlookup function inside Large or Small functions?
I get a formula error when I try to do this

=Large((Vlookup("xxx",Table1,2,0),Vlookup("yyy",Table1,2,0),Vlookup("zzz",Table1,2,0)),2)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution would be: `=LARGE(VLOOKUP({"xxx","yyy","zzz"},Table1,2,0),2)`

[image]

Older Excel versions require this to be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`.

Answer (score 1):

use CHOOSE:

```
=Large(CHOOSE({1,2,3},Vlookup("xxx",Table1,2,0),Vlookup("yyy",Table1,2,0),Vlookup("zzz",Table1,2,0)),2)
```

Older versions may need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when confirming the edit.

Or if you have it HSTACK:

```
=Large(HSTACK(Vlookup("xxx",Table1,2,0),Vlookup("yyy",Table1,2,0),Vlookup("zzz",Table1,2,0)),2)
```